# onfocusout not triggering handler function

Tags: angular

I have the following HTML. I want to set a field as `touched` once focus is lost from it.

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="validateField('firstName')" (focusout)="setFieldStatus('firstName')" required>
```

But my function is not getting called. I do not see any console messages.

```
setFieldStatus(field:string){
    console.log("inside setFieldStatus for field "+field)
    const control = this.signupForm.get(field);             
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {             
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true }); 
      }
  };
```

Am I not using `(onfocusout)` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Angular, it's:

```
(blur)="setFieldStatus('firstName')"
```